# How to click the link via Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
<a href="eventLog.cgi?command=0" target="content" class="Menu_titleFont">View Event Log</a>
```

How to click the `"view event log"` in `selenium`? 
I have tried

```
By.CssSelector("a[href^='eventLog.cgi?command=0']")
```

but `"NoSuchElementException was unhandled"` error occured.

Comment: give us the html of the link so we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to wait until element is present in `DOM` as below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("a[href='eventLog.cgi?command=0']")));
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.LinkText("View Event Log")));
```

If your element located inside `iframe`, you might need to use

```
webDriver.SwitchTo().Frame("menu");
```

before searching for element

Comment: `webDriver` is just instance of your `webdriver`, e.g `IWebDriver webDriver = new SafariDriver();`. Just replace it with your current variable name (`driver`, `browser`...)

Comment: i replaced with driver and then WebDriverTimeoutException was unhanled occurs

Comment: Does it located inside `<iframe>`? Check ancestors

Comment: Can you share target page `URL`?

Comment: Can you share more details about this issue: how does this link looks like, which pre-conditions you should complete to see this link on page, like click on button to open drop-down menu or something... or link just initially present on page?

Comment: after login, the main page came. in left nevigation there is "View Event Log". there is no drop-down menu

Comment: If so, then it most likely to be caused by `iframe`... Are you sure that there are no `iframes` on the page? Can you check it again?

Comment: <frame src="cgi-bin/menuAdmin.cgi" name="menu" scrolling="AUTO" noresize="">  i couldnot find iframe. but i found this.

Comment: Try `webDriver.SwitchTo().Frame("menu");` before clicking link

Comment: Great :) Please mark this answer as "Accepted" if it solved your problem. Thanks